not saving the WC_Session_Handler session and removing the product from the cart session in WooCommerce's custom rest api
I have spent almost two days on this problem.
I want to write a dedicated REST API for WooCommerce that removes a product from the user's shopping cart.
I delete the product, but unfortunately the new session is not saved I tested many models of the set() method, but none of them saved the session.
Please guide me if you know what is the problem with my code and why the new session is not saved thank you.

// Hook into REST API initialization
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_rest_endpoint');
// Register custom REST API endpoint
function register_custom_rest_endpoint()
{
  
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/cart/remove', array(
        'methods' => 'DELETE',
        'callback' => 'handle_remove_product_from_cart',
    ));
}

function handle_remove_product_from_cart($data)
{
    $user_email = sanitize_email($data['email']);
    $product_id = intval($data['product_id']);
    $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);
    if (!$user) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array('error' => 'User not found.'), 404);
    }

    $session_handler = new WC_Session_Handler();
    $session = $session_handler->get_session($user->ID);
    $cart_items = maybe_unserialize($session['cart']);

    if (empty($cart_items)) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array('message' => 'Cart is empty.'), 200);
    }

    foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if ($cart_item['product_id'] === $product_id) {
            // Remove the product from the cart
            unset($cart_items[$cart_item_key]);
            break; // Stop searching after finding the product
        }
    }
 
    // remove product from old session
    $session['cart'] = serialize($cart_items);

    // new session not saving
    $session_handler->set($session['cart'], $session);// for test
    $session_handler->set($user->ID, $session['cart']); // for test
    $session_handler->set($user->ID, serialize($cart_items));// for test
    $session_handler->set(serialize($cart_items), $session);// for test
    $session_handler->set(serialize($cart_items), $user->ID);// for test
    $session_handler->save_data( ); // not set and not saving new session
 
    return new WP_REST_Response(array('message' => 'Product removed from cart.'), 200);
}

I spent almost two days trying to create a new cart session using the set() and save() methods, but there was no result. I just want the new session to be saved for the user after the product is removed from the user's shopping cart.
